# what is the complexity/BIG O of this function "loops"

Tags: c, loops, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
void mystery2 (int n)
{
  int i;
 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   double x = i;
   double delta = 1 / (double)i;
   while ( x > 0 )
     x -= delta;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Why is the BIG O, The time complexity of this function is O(n^3) and not O(n^2)?

What I done is when i=1 ==> 1 iterations, i=2 ==> 2iterations(in while) i=3 ==> 3 iteration ........ i=n ==> n iteration, if we sum all the iterations we get 1+2+3+4....+n = n*(n+1)/2. so what I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because inner loop runs like this.

```
For i=1, inner loop runs 1 time,
For i=2, inner loop runs 4 time,
 //because x=2 and delta=0.5 so for x to become 0 it has to iterate 4 time 
For i=3, inner loop runs 9 time
 //because x=3 and delta=0.33 so for x to become 0 it has to iterate 9(atleast) time 
and so on..
```

So inner loop run `i^2` time and the equation becomes `1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6` which is equal to O(n^3) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at it as a standard integer decrement loop, which I also did at first, but the number are doubles, and `delta` is not `1` but actually `1 / (double)i`, so the number of inner loop iterations it takes to fully decrement `x` does not increase linearly as `n` increases, but much more sharply, because `delta` gets smaller as `n` gets larger.